# Problema con Media Queries CSS

Tags: html, asp.net, css3

Buenas días, compañeros. Vengo con la siguiente duda.

Tengo una media query para poner un fondo de pantalla en mi master, situada en el **body**.

```
body {
    background : url('../../escritorio.png');
    background-size : cover !important;
    background-repeat : no-repeat !important;
    background-position : center center !important;
    background-attachment : fixed !important;
    background-color: #464646;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
    body {
        background : url('../../movil.png');
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

En cuestiones de escritorio todo va perfecto pero al momento de usar Safari mobile o incluso, el mismo Chrome mobile.
En Safari la imagen me aparece desfasada, como si estuviera usando la imagen para navegadores mientras que en Chrome ni siquiera me muestra la imagen.

Como dato extra, ya tengo incluido la etiqueta **meta** en mi master.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

P.D. En el único navegador que me funciona es en IE del Win 10 mobile.

P.D.2 Anexo imágenes de como se ve en IE del Win 10 mobile y como se ve en chromme mobile de android

[image: Win 10 mobile]

[image: chromme mobile de android]

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste poner backgroundsize: cover; ? Ademas de los prefijos de los navegadores

Comment: Si hablas de meterlo en la media query, si ya lo intenten, tengo entendido que para eso es el prefijo !important, si no encuentra una propiedad que se especifica en el css de la query, usara esa misma.

Comment: ¿Podrias proporcionarnos la URL para ver más a detalle? Y poder solucionarlo más rápido.

Comment: No puedo, es un sitio donde solamente tienen acceso usuario internos de la empresa para poder capturar sus cosas, es ahí donde la imagen no me aparece de manera correcta en los móviles, podria anexar imágenes para mayor apreciación ?

Comment: Si, claro, anexalas. También sube las imagenes sobre los errores que se pueden presentar en la parte de Developer Tools de Chrome/Mozilla.

Comment: Listo, espero esto ayude para que se me pueda entender mejor.

Comment: ¿Qué aparece en Developer Tools?

Comment: Puedo abrir el Developer Tools en el movil ? por que en el del navegador no me sale ningún error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de estar cambiando estilo tras estilo, al fin encontré la combinación que a mi me funciono, no puedo asegurar que le funcione a todos o que sea la mejor respuesta pero aquí esta el código CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: url('escritorio.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    body {
        background: url('movil.png');
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
}
```

Espero ayude !